# Define attributes of network nodes by comparing them with a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, networkx

I have a .gml file like the one below:

```
graph [
  directed 1
  node [
    id 0
    label "5B5F2C071D12AF13219DF5EBE05132AF"
  ]
  node [
    id 1
    label "9FB3B96B6D5E16C9DD564AA3E84F1954"
  ]
  node [
    id 2
    label "B3299B0E587D7275E3E4D530E9EECF50"
  ]
  node [
    id 3
    label "6432F1DF21BA38368D9A165C739EEBB3"
  ]
  node [
    id 4
    label "85D5C50A6D882CA8E4BB00BCA3574417"
  ]
  node [
    id 5
    label "0D8583F810B9720A8032BB939F12B3FF"
  ]
  node [
    id 6
    label "6C10A9E9F325CAA3CCB7F9A0D6983D2A"
  ]
  node [
    id 7
    label "B0C50ED1DEC9E06E4C64E7419DDC4B09"
  ]
]
```

I need to add an attribute called class on each node of the network, which represents a socioeconomic classification. I have a dictionary, containing the node id and class, as follows:

```
dict_users = {"5B5F2C071D12AF13219DF5EBE05132AF": 3,
              "9FB3B96B6D5E16C9DD564AA3E84F1954": 2,
              "B3299B0E587D7275E3E4D530E9EECF50": 3,
              "6432F1DF21BA38368D9A165C739EEBB3": 2,
              "85D5C50A6D882CA8E4BB00BCA3574417": 3,
              "0D8583F810B9720A8032BB939F12B3FF": 2,
              "6C10A9E9F325CAA3CCB7F9A0D6983D2A": 3,
              "B0C50ED1DEC9E06E4C64E7419DDC4B09": 2}
```

However, when I traverse the network over the dictionary, all nodes receive the value of the last one in the dictionary. Below is the complete code:

```
import pandas as pd
import networkx as nx
G = nx.read_gml('/home/gustavo/Desktop/Mestrado/mestrado_dados/Redes/Teste.gml')

dict_users = {"5B5F2C071D12AF13219DF5EBE05132AF": 3,
              "9FB3B96B6D5E16C9DD564AA3E84F1954": 2,
              "B3299B0E587D7275E3E4D530E9EECF50": 3,
              "6432F1DF21BA38368D9A165C739EEBB3": 2,
              "85D5C50A6D882CA8E4BB00BCA3574417": 3,
              "0D8583F810B9720A8032BB939F12B3FF": 2,
              "6C10A9E9F325CAA3CCB7F9A0D6983D2A": 3,
              "B0C50ED1DEC9E06E4C64E7419DDC4B09": 3}

for i in G.nodes:
    for j in dict_users.keys():
        if i == j:
            nx.set_node_attributes(G, dict_users.get(j), 'class')
```

Can anyone tell me what I should do so that each node receives value corresponding to it as it is in the dictionary? Also, is there any way to make the iteration between the network and the dictionary computationally less costly? the real .gml file is much larger, as is the dictionary.

Comment: If your dictionary covers all nodes, you can just avoid the second loop. `for i in G.nodes: nx.set_node_attributes(G, dict_users.get(i), 'class')`

Comment: If not, you can make a default value for nodes not in dictionary by providing a second argument to the get function call. https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer, but it is still very computationally expensive:

```
import pandas as pd
import networkx as nx
G = nx.read_gml('/home/gustavo/Desktop/Mestrado/mestrado_dados/Redes/Teste.gml')

dict_users = {"5B5F2C071D12AF13219DF5EBE05132AF": 3,
              "9FB3B96B6D5E16C9DD564AA3E84F1954": 2,
              "B3299B0E587D7275E3E4D530E9EECF50": 3,
              "6432F1DF21BA38368D9A165C739EEBB3": 2,
              "85D5C50A6D882CA8E4BB00BCA3574417": 3,
              "0D8583F810B9720A8032BB939F12B3FF": 2,
              "6C10A9E9F325CAA3CCB7F9A0D6983D2A": 3,
              "B0C50ED1DEC9E06E4C64E7419DDC4B09": 3}

for i in G.nodes:
    for j in dict_users.keys():
        if i == j:
            G.nodes[i]['class'] = dict_users.get(j)
```